# Get ID, Class of Currently Focused Element in Selenium

Tags: java, facebook, selenium-webdriver, automation, focus

There are many ways to select or focus an element in Selenium, for example using TAB key we can focus on next element.
But, is there any way in Selenium to get all details of current focused element such as id, class, href, text etc ?
i want to focus on Like, Comment or Share button of a post https://www.facebook.com/pitbull/photos/a.440436327400.230702.95051637400/10153236215477401/?type=3&theater of Facebook page of Pitbull, But nothing works for me, i tried xpath, class, id but unable to Focus on share button. i can focus on share button using Tab key about 161 times but how will i confirm that focused element is "Share" button or somethong else? ;)
Here is my sample code

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("myemail@yahoo.com");
driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

after TAB key, you know focus will be go to Password field from email field, so how can i get id, class or other details of focused element in my selenium code? in my example it is Password field.

Comment: side question: may i ask about the use case for this? selenium is a testing tool, so...why test facebook? ;)

Comment: I thought Selenium focus it automatically, doesn't it?

Comment: Learning Automation. and it is very difficult to automate Facebook. anyway i was searching a way to get details of focused element just like HTMLunit has such function.

Comment: Hello, Roman C, Sorry i did not understand what you say.

Comment: nop, post the code what did you try, because nobody can understand what you have written

Comment: i added a code to make you understand what i need :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
WebElement activeElement = driver.switchTo().activeElement(); 
String className =  activeElement.getAttribute("class"); 
String id = activeElement.getAttribute("id");
```